# iis 8 Application Pool stops automatically when opening a web site

Tags: windows-7, iis-8

Whenever I try to open or browse a web site in iis 8, the application pool stops and I get an error 503- service unavailable. I opened windows event viewer for error log and it gives me the following error:

"A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '3088' serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' reported a listener channel failure.  The data field contains the error number."

I'm currently using Windows 7.

I tried a dozen things for 6 hours and i'm at wits end! Any suggestions will be apreciated!

Comment: Do you have the full event log entry?   Also you have checked that the identify running the application pool has access to the directory hosting the site and that the identity credentials are correct if set.

Comment: The identity is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity and the Load User Profile is set to false.

Comment: Full error:- System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-WAS 
   [ Guid]  {524B5D04-133C-4A62-8362-64E8EDB9CE40} 
   [ EventSourceName]  WAS 
 
  - EventID 5139 
   [ Qualifiers]  32768 
   Version 0  
   Level 3 
   Task 0 
 
   Opcode 0  
   Keywords 0x80000000000000  
  
  ProcessID 3088 
  param3 0 
  ProtocolID http 
   FB2A0780 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Binary data:


In Words
0000: 80072AFB    
In Bytes
0000: FB 2A 07 80               û*.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by simply resetting iis. Go to command prompt, right click to run as administrator, then type "iisreset" and press enter.